# Silverlight: Events in datatemplate for listboxes

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, datatemplate

The functionality I want is to have a remove button beside each item of a listbox so when the user clicks it, that specific item gets removed from the list.

I am thinking about putting it in the data template but how would I wire up an even to that?

Thanks,
Shawn Mclean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to approach this issue.  Create an ObservableCollection and set you ItemsSource equal to that Collection.  Then your Button click handler can just remove the item.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace SilverlightApplication1
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        private ObservableCollection<string> _customers;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _customers = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "Bob", "Mark", "Steve" };
            this.DataContext = _customers;
        }

        public void remove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var button = sender as Button;
            if (button == null)
                return;

            var name = button.DataContext as string;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
                return;

            _customers.Remove(name);
        }
    }
}
```

In this sample your XAML would look like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                    <Button Content="Remove" Click="remove_Click" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind ItemsSource of your ListBox to ObservableCollection.
Put a delete button into data template.
Click event handler for the button can be something like this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as Button;
    if (button != null)
    {
        var yourObject = button.DataContext as YourObject;
        if (yourObject != null)
        {
            YourObjectsObservableCollection.Remove(yourObject); 
        }
    }
}
```

So you can retrieve the object which is bound to ListBoxItem from buttons DataContext.